# CGRect with variable Buttons per Row

Tags: objective-c, view, cgrect

Following situation:

i want to build a `cgrect`. what i need is: up to 4 rows. up to 6 columns.

so for example how it have to look:

i need min.

`+  +  +  +`
(1 row, 4 buttons)

and max i need:

`+  +  +  +  +  +
  +  +  +  +  + 
 +  +  +  +  +  +
  +  +  +  +  +`

(4 rows, 22 buttons)

what i want is to pass the `BUTTONS_FOR_ROW1-4` data from an other `VC`. for the min example this is button_for_row1 = 4, button_for_row2 = 0, button_for_row3 = 0, button_for_row4 = 0.

for the max example button_for_row1 = 6, button_for_row2 = 5, button_for_row3 = 6, button_for_row4 = 5

my code now is this:

```
-(void) generateCardViews {
int positionsLeftInRow = _BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
int j = 0; // j = ROWNUMBER (j = 0) = ROW1, (j = 1) = ROW2...

for (int i = 0; i < [self.gameModel.buttons count]; i++) {
    NSInteger value = ((ButtonModel *)self.gameModel.buttons[i]).value;

    CGFloat x = (i % _BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 121 + (i % _BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 40 + 285;
    if (j == 1) {
        x += 80; // set additional indent (horizontal displacement)
    }
    if (j == 2) {
        x -= 160;
    }

    CGFloat y = j * 122 + j * 40 + 158;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 125, 125);




    ButtonView *cv = [[ButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPosition:i andValue:value];

    if (!((ButtonModel *)self.gameModel.buttons[i]).outOfPlay) {
        [self.boardView addSubview:cv];

       if ([self.gameModel.turnedButtons containsObject: self.gameModel.buttons[i]]) {
            [self.turnedButtonViews addObject: cv];
            [cv flip];
        }
    }

    if (--positionsLeftInRow == 0) {
        j++;
        positionsLeftInRow = _BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
        if (j == 1) {
            positionsLeftInRow = _BUTTONS_PER_ROW-1;

        if (j == 2) {
            positionsLeftInRow = _BUTTONS_PER_ROW-2;
        }}
    }
}
}
```

As you can see my code now have just BUTTONS_PER_ROW and not BUTTONS_FOR_ROW1 - 4.

the indent is for pushing a row left or right.

But i think this will work much easier, cause with my code i get some weird things when i make 22 Buttons.

thanks for help!

Comment: Use a `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic logic can be simplified. I would use a while loop here. For the case of a maximum number of buttons per row (the simpler case), this is an outline of what I think is a clear way to do what you want:

```
y = .... (initial value of y)
NSUInteger numberOfButtons = [self.gameModel.buttons count];

// Layout out the buttons, with no more than _BUTTONS_PER_ROW in each row

NSUInteger buttonsLeft = numberOfButtons;
NSUInteger buttonsInRow = 0;
while(buttonsLeft>0)
{

    if(buttonsInRow>_BUTTONS_PER_ROW)
    {
        // Increment y, reset x
        y += ....
        x = .... (initial position for x)
        buttonsInRow = 0;
    }
    // Create a button
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 125, 125);
    ButtonView* buttonView = [[ButtonView .....
    x += 80;

    ++buttonsInRow;
    --buttonsLeft;
}
```

For the more general case, add a variable to keep track of the row number, and use and array with the maximum number of buttons per row that is loaded before entering the while loop.